# Unable to print JSON object values in view.ejs when response from controller return JSON object when database call is made

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I have JSON response from database query through controller and I would like to print this JSON object values in view.ejs file.

view.ejs

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
  <td>{{ x.username}}</td>
  <td>{{ x.password}}</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("")  
 .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.users;});
});
</script>
```

This is my Model 
User.js

```
  module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,

  attributes: {

   username:{
       type:'string',
       required: true,
       unique:true
    },
    password:{
       type:'string',
       required:true
    },
   }
 };
```

This is my controller 
UserController.js

```
   module.exports = {
     get:function(req,res){
       User.find().exec(function (err, users){
          if (err) {
              return res.json(err);
           }

          return res.json(users);
       });
     }
  };
```

I am configuring routes in below file
routes.js

```
 module.exports.routes = {

   '/': {
      view: 'view'
    },

   '/user/get': 'UserController.get',

 };
```

when I hit URL "http://localhost:1337/user/get", I get this below json response and I want this values to be pushed into view.ejs file.

```
[
  {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "id": 1
 },
  {
    "username": "home",
    "password": "home",
    "id": 2
  },
 {
    "username": "unisys",
    "password": "unisys",
    "id": 3
 }
]
```

I would like to know if somebody can help me to understand how i can get these values.Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: try to add this in your view {{names}}are you getting users in their

Comment: No I am not getting values.Please keep suggesting

Comment: after this $scope.names = response.users -> add $scope.$apply($scope.names) in your controller and check for {{names}} in your views

Comment: console.log(response) to make sure that users are available in their or not

Comment: what should be parameter to http.get(); method in this case. I am passing $http.get("http://localhost:1337/user/get").then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data; $scope.$apply($scope.names)}); Is this correct way?

Comment: before all this check for response using console.log(response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in assigning `names` from `response` data. i.e,

use

> $scope.names = response.**data**.users; OR $scope.names = response.**data**;

instead of

> $scope.names = response.users;

Comment: he is returning whole users and not using data objects

Comment: Yes Correct I am returning whole user object and Does $http.get("") method needs URL here?

Comment: If you are use promise with angular `http` then some meta data automatic added in response object. e.g: `Object{data=[3],status:"200",statusText="OK",config={}}`

Answer (score 0):

In response itself you are getting array of objects so if you assign it directly to $scope.names , it will work.

if it helps you, just let me know .

$http.get("localhost:1337/user/get").then(function (response) {$scope.names = response;
console.log(response) ;
})